# Facebook Graph Page Posts Successful But Not Showing On Feed For All

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I'm a bit stumped with a Facebook Graph API issue here. I'm using the Facebook  PHP Graph API to post to a Facebook page, authenticating as myself with "manage_pages" and "publish_pages", and posting a scheduled post.

The problem is that, where the account which I was offering Graph the access token with (my own personal account) can see the posts getting published, and see them on the wall... Other accounts cannot see a thing that graph is posting. See screenshots below between the two facebook accounts:

My FB Account - https://pasteboard.co/Hd6XWYN.png

Another FB Account (albeit a page admin also) -
 https://pasteboard.co/Hd6Yw9W.png

The Facebook page has full visibility permissions without restriction. The posting account can see the timeline posts, others cannot despite the posts being "visibility=everyone".

Does anyone know why this behavior is occurring?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: If your Facebook application is in "development mode", only you (or other admins/developers/testers of the app) can see what it creates.

Comment: Yes, that sounds like the issue, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Your Facebook App needs to be public/live, or the posts will not be visible for regular users.

Comment: Thanks !

Note the application has to be «Live», but if some permissions requires a facebook employee to validate, you can already use your app by yourself.